# Proving the Convolution of PDFs gives a PDF

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, density-function, convolution

I am struggling with a question about the convolution of PDFs, in particular, proving that given two PDFs $f$ and $g$, then their convolution $f*g$, will also be a PDF. Proving non negativity is easy but I am struggling to show that the integrals has value $1$. Here is my proof so far:

Note that all these integrals are evaluated over the reals.
$$\int (f*g)(x)\text{d}x = \iint f(y)g(x-y) \text{d}y  \text{d}x$$

Let $ z = x-y $
\begin{align*}
\iint f(y)g(z)\text{d}y\text{d}z&= \int f(y) \text{d}y \int g(z) \text{d}z\\
&= 1
\end{align*}

I have the answer but I believe I have made an error with the changing of the limits of substitution when I introduce the new variable $z$. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your first equality is missing an integral sign on the right side. There should be two.

Comment: Nothing wrong about this derivation: the Jacobian is equal to $1$.

Comment: How did you go from $z=x-y$ to $dx = dz$?

Comment: The answer given in this post is of course complete bogus, if someone is in search for a serious proof, refer to this:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2909871/convolution-theorem-for-probability/2910765#2910765

Answer (score 16):

You are looking at a final result rather than where the convolution came from. Starting from an earlier point makes the proof easier.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with densities
$f$ and $g$ respectively, then
\begin{align}
P\{X+Y \leq z\} &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty P\{X+Y \leq z \mid Y = y\}g(y)\,\mathrm dy & \scriptstyle{\text{law of total probability}}\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty P\{X \leq z-y \mid Y = y\}g(y)\,\mathrm dy\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty P\{X \leq z-y\}g(y)\,\mathrm dy&
\scriptstyle{\text{independence of}~X~\text{and}~Y}\\
P\{X+Y \leq z\} &=\int_{-\infty}^\infty 
\left[ \int_{-\infty}^{z-y} f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right]g(y)\,\mathrm dy
\tag{1}
\end{align}
Note that the left side of $(1)$ has limiting value $1$ as
$z \to \infty$; in fact, the value of that double integral
on the right is the CDF of the random variable $Z = X+Y$.
The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus applied to $(1)$
gives us
$$f_{X+Y}(z) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}P\{X+Y \leq z\}
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z-y)g(y)\,\mathrm dy
= f\star g$$
and so
$\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb R} f\star g = 1$ as you wish to prove.

Comment: From the book!  Very nice proof.

Comment: I prefer the notation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1820625/373043),  which predates this post.

Comment: The proof looks good, except for the very last part. PDF is the derivative of the CDF by its definition (not by the Fundamental theorem of calculus). The only catch is when you differentiate under the integral sign. Here you apply the Leibniz integral rule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement).